# Car rental Tenerife Sur (south) airport at 2am in the night?

Tags: car-rentals, spain, tenerife

I'm trying to rent a car for a few days.

Location: Tenerife / Spain / Tenerife Sur / Tenerife-Reina Sofia
Time: May - landing 1am - so I need something at 2-3am.

I tried the main ones like Avis and Budget; they state that they are not working at that time and I can't rent it.

I found a couple of others that allow it, but they are not very trustworthy.

Can someone who has been there, or lives there, recommend some trustworthy site for car rental that would allow a 2am pickup? Are there any that are open that time?

Or, worst case scenario, provide some information about ways and prices to get to Adeje at that time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've visited the Canary Islands several times and rented cars from Cicar. It was recommended by a German travel guide (book) as reliable company.

Cicar is a native car rental company and claims to be the largest one on the Canary Islands, with the most offices.

Personally, I had no problems with their cars or their service and would choose them again. (However, I only rented cars three times at different locations) Nice goodie: You get a (simple) map with points of interest and an audio-CD giving some information about that points.

According to Cicars web site, office hours at Tenerife South airport are 7:00-23:00, 7 days/week. But their conditions also state that you can also rent cars outside of their office hours. (See [here](http://www.cicar.com/EN/view/condiciones-popup_EN) or goto http://www.cicar.com/EN, click "search", and find the link [see conditions] on the left, below the booking details)

OK, this sounds more like an advertisement, but I'm just a pleased customer.